Spring Webflow application doesn't work on Multi node OpenLiberty with session externalized to Redis cache
We are trying to port our Spring Weblflow application (Websites) from WebSphere App Server to OpenLiberty WebProfile 8 as part of the Cloud Migration program. Before kick off, as PoC we built a very simple war with webflow 2.4 having 2 flows, each having 2 pages. To achieve high availability 2 node deployment is done where session is externalized to Redis Cache. Article posted at Configuring Open Liberty or WebSphere Liberty Session Persistence With JCache and Redis is referred for the configuring distributed Session persistence.
PoC application work fine on the single node. But doesn't work when you jump to other server from same bowser (by executing the flow url with ip and port of the other server), Application shows the first page properly with correct value for programmatically set session variable. But When you try to navigate to other page, it gives error that it failed to retrieve the 2nd snapshot and throws exception.
Has anyone tried these thing. Then please help us in solving the issue.
Please Note :-

We have use the Community version of Redis for our PoC and not Redis Pro
Same experience on WebSphere Liberty developer version.
But same PoC work correctly on Tomcat and Redis Community version. (Multi node with externalized session)


----------- Update => Adding Configuration files and versions --------------------------

Liberty :-  webProfile8-24.0.0.5 (Windows 64bit)
JDK :- 1.8.0_151 (Windows 64bit)
Redis :- 3.2.100 64 bit for Windows.
Tomcat :- 8.5.87 (Windows 64bit)


Liberty server.xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<server description="new server">

<!-- Enable features -->
<featureManager>
    <feature>webProfile-8.0</feature>
    <feature>sessionCache-1.0</feature>
</featureManager>

<!-- To access this server from a remote client add a host attribute to the following element, e.g. host="*" -->
<httpEndpoint id="defaultHttpEndpoint"
              httpPort="9085"
              httpsPort="9433" />
              
<!-- Automatically expand WAR files and EAR files -->
<applicationManager autoExpand="true"/>

<library id="jCacheVendorLib">
    <file name="${shared.resource.dir}/redisson-all-3.25.2.jar"/>
    <file name="${shared.resource.dir}/fst-2.57.jar"/>
</library>

<httpSessionCache cacheManagerRef="CacheManager"/>

<cacheManager id="CacheManager" uri="file:${server.config.dir}/redisson.yaml">
    <properties fallback="true"/>
    <cachingProvider jCacheLibraryRef="jCacheVendorLib"/>
</cacheManager>

<logging traceSpecification="*=audit:org.springframework.webflow.*=finest"/>

</server>


Redis redisson.yaml
singleServerConfig:
  idleConnectionTimeout: 10000
  connectTimeout: 10000
  timeout: 3000
  retryAttempts: 3
  retryInterval: 1500
  password: null
  subscriptionsPerConnection: 5
  clientName: null
  address: "redis://127.0.0.1:6379"
  subscriptionConnectionMinimumIdleSize: 1
  subscriptionConnectionPoolSize: 50
  connectionMinimumIdleSize: 1
  connectionPoolSize: 5
  database: 0
  dnsMonitoringInterval: 5000
threads: 16
nettyThreads: 32
codec: !<org.redisson.codec.FstCodec> {}
transportMode: "NIO"


See what session trace might show you. https://www.ibm.com/support/pages/node/81081#LibertyTrace

Also, maybe provide your exact Liberty and redis configurations
